# Boltzmann's papers

Tags: special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

I wonder if anyone knows where i can find the main papers of Boltzmann translated in English. Especially his  monumental work on 1877 
*"On the Relationship between the Second Fundamental Theorem of the Mechanical
Theory of Heat and Probability Calculations Regarding the
Conditions for Thermal Equilibrium"*

Comment: Where does the first link take you if you Google search it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because specific reference requests on Phys.SE are usually limited to case that are not easy to find.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the translation of the paper [here](http://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/17/4/1971)

Comment: A collective archive of his papers or even of the titles concentrated?